# Untarring into a temp directory, then deleting the directory

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tar

I'm a very new linux user, and I'm untarring a tarball into a directory, *say that without smiling*.

What I want to do is create a temp directory with the `mktemp -d` command and use the `tar` command to untar the tarball into the temporary directory, then I want to delete the directory (I'm pretty sure I have an idea on how I'm going t do this).

What I have so far is this...

`tar -xvzf UW_archive_example.tgz home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/example.ods`

This works and successfully untars the file, how would I implement `mktemp -d` with the `tar` command so that it untars the file into the temp directory?

*Assume I am unable to download anything and only have read access in the directory I want to create the temp in.*

Comment: If you only have read permissions, I don't see how you can create any files, temporary or permanent. ..

Comment: @Xen2050 The people who are using this program will have full access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do this:

```
tar -C `mktemp -d` -xvf foo.tar
```

Which extracts foo.tar into a temp directory but that is only technically correct because it doesn't tell you where the directory is.

a two line approach would be:

```
NEW_TMP_DIR=`mktemp -d`
tar -C $NEW_TMP_DIR -xvf foo.tar
```

and if you want to chain them you can with && to make it one liner and ensure the directory was created:

```
NEW_TMP_DIR=`mktemp -d` && tar -C $NEW_TMP_DIR -xvf foo.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

mktmp -d --tmpdir=/path/to/untar/dir && tar -C /path/to/untar/dir -xvzf UW_archive_example.tar home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/example.ods

mktmp creates your temporary directory in the path of your choosing. tar's -C gives the directory to untar to. The '&&' ensures the tar will only run if the mktmp command was successful. You can test this with a dir you have write access to before handing it off to those will access to the final target dir.